# Flutter Button Click and Button Color Control

Tags: flutter, button, colors

I have six buttons on the screen and they all do the same function. But I want to control the colors of these buttons to be clicked. If the button is clicked, the button color should be green (I'm doing this buttonColorDisable.) Everything is normal so far, but in _buttonFunction() widget.callbackColor(); When I call it, I expect all button colors to change again, but only the last button is affected. Other buttons still remain green. how do i solve this.

```
class BuildNumButton extends StatefulWidget {
final int number;
final Color color;
final Color buttonColorDisable;
final Function callbackColor;
final Function callbackList;
final Function callbackScore;
final Function callbackTarget;

const BuildNumButton({
Key? key,
required this.number,
required this.callbackScore,
required this.callbackList,
required this.callbackTarget,
required this.callbackColor,
required this.color,
required this.buttonColorDisable,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<BuildNumButton> createState() => _BuildNumButtonState();
}

class _BuildNumButtonState extends State<BuildNumButton> {
bool isButtonVisible = false;

void _buttonFunction() {
isButtonVisible = true;
CalculateScore.sumNumbers(widget.number);
CalculateScore.calculateScore();
widget.callbackScore();
if (CalculateScore.answer == true) {
  if (!CalculateScore.endGame) {
    widget.callbackList();
    widget.callbackColor();
    isButtonVisible = false;
  }
  widget.callbackTarget();
 }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SizedBox(
  width: 150,
  height: 120,
  child: TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: isButtonVisible
          ? MaterialStateProperty.all(
              widget.buttonColorDisable) //button color green
          : MaterialStateProperty.all(widget.color),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: isButtonVisible ? null : _buttonFunction,
    child: Text(
      widget.number.toString(),
      style: numButtonTextStyle,
     ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer creating `List<int>` to hold tapped index and use `BuildNumButton extends StatelessWidget`.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=fa5a69ba16669b70071ebbd5cc3d3092).

```dart
class BuildNumButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final Color color;
  final Color buttonColorDisable;
  final VoidCallback callback;
  final bool isDisable;

  const BuildNumButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.color,
    required this.buttonColorDisable,
    required this.callback,
    required this.isDisable,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 150,
      height: 120,
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: isDisable
              ? MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  buttonColorDisable) //button color green
              : MaterialStateProperty.all(color),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: isDisable ? null : callback,
        child: Text(
          number.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and  `VoidCallback` used to get tapEvent and based on condition update the state.

```dart
List<int> disableButtons = [];

.....

...List.generate(
  6,
  (index) => BuildNumButton(
    buttonColorDisable: Colors.green,
    isDisable: disableButtons.contains(index),
    callback: () {
      disableButtons.add(index);

      if (disableButtons.length == 6) disableButtons.clear();
      setState(() {});
    },
    color: Colors.cyanAccent,
    number: index,
  ),
)
```

Comment: I can't find where is the error, but when I add it to my own code, it doesn't work. can you take a look here   https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=20a01ffcb8f48602a5a5498d3a52f764  @Yeasin

Comment: There is another `disableButtons` list just under the build method, remove it.

Comment: oh yes I fixed it now, so where do I call the _buttonFunction(),  I said call both callback and _buttonfunction with if else in onPressed, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `callback:(){... your coditional state}`

Comment: oh yeah i understood and got it done. thank you very much. this problem took my days. thanks thanksrr thanks.......